# what happened to MP4V2 library

Tags: c++, mp4

I have an application which uses MP4V2, but looking around I noted that it is on Google archive site.

Does it replace with another library?

Does it merge with another library?

Comment: Most projects moved to GitHub, and there are plenty of copies of mp4v2 on GitHub, but it's not obvious if there's a central one where new development is happening. FWIW [Fedora Linux still builds their package](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/libmp4v2/tree/master) from the googlecode version plus a number of patches.

Comment: Google likes to abandon its projects, almost 200 so far abandoned, see https://killedbygoogle.com/

Comment: @AndreyBelykh Just because something was hosted on Google Code doesn't mean it was a Google project, any more than something hosted on Github is a Github project.

Comment: It seems that library is dead (see e.g. [this Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=921127)) you can probably use some actively maintained alternative like the libraries from [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) (maybe [Libavformat](https://www.ffmpeg.org/libavformat.html)?)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the one of well maintained fork.
https://github.com/TechSmith/mp4v2

I used it for few years already, I created own fork where I just host windows builds.
https://github.com/yermak/mp4v2/releases